# What is the name of this exercise where you lie flat on your back and then touch your feet, without bending your knees?

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

Can anyone tell me what is the name of the following exercise?

1. Lie straight (first image)
2. Touch your feet (second image).

[image]

Comment: This is a weird question, but perhaps it's a **sit-up**?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sit-up

Comment: Yeah, "sit-up".

Comment: aka 'trunk curl'

Comment: @MaxWilliams In, Sit-ups we bend our knees, But knees in my Image are flat to the ground.

Comment: @user40044 perhaps a "straight leg sit-up" then. eg http://www.popsugar.com/fitness/photo-gallery/30828261/image/37584225/Core-Straight-Leg-Sit-Up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Fitness site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be called (body) **roll-up** on several places, giving only a couple:

- http://greatist.com/move/best-exercises-lower-abs
- http://www.realsimple.com/health/fitness-exercise/workouts/lower-abdominal-exercises/move-roll-up

[image: Roll-up]

However, it is not listed yet on the wikipedia [roll-up  disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-up).

Answer (score 0):

That's **a type of abdominal workout**, and can be called by different names depending on where you are from. If your aim is to get a flat belly, it's called **a flat stomach or flat belly workout**.
As you can see, such a position stretches the back of your legs and, therefore, it's also a **leg stretching** exercise (or **active leg-stretching**). In this case, you can do it either lying on the floor or standing up (as you can see in the figure below, positions 3 and 9

Conclusion: I'd call it a **leg-stretching sit-up** as it works the belly and stretches the calves at the same time.

**[image: flat stomach workout]**